# Pad left with zeroes if less than 7 digits

Tags: abap

There is a variable type char18. If the value of the variable is less than 7 digits add leading zeros to make it 7 digits.

If it's greater than 7 digits don't change the value.

For example.

- If the value of the variable is 234.
- It should come as 0000234
- If it's 12345678 result should be 12345678

```
IF STRLEN( lv_meter_no ) LT 7.
  CONCATENATE '0000000' lv_meter_no INTO lv_meter_no RESPECTING BLANKS.
  lv_meter_no = lv_meter_no+1(7). "Take the rightmost 7 characters 
ENDIF.
```

Actual output:

- If I am giving 278
- I am getting the output as 4 278
- It should come as 0000278

Comment: You can use standard conversion exit ALPHA for this.

Comment: It seems you ask "give me the final program" (?), I don't see a precise question. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see how to ask questions, e.g. explain the context, provide a minimal reproducible example, etc.

Comment: `lv_meter_no = lv_meter_no+1(7).` will not take the rightmost characters …

Answer (score 0):

Use string templates to get the desired transformation:

`lv_meter_no = |{ lv_meter_no ALPHA = IN WIDTH = 7 }|.`

Notes from the documentation:

**ALPHA = IN**: If the character string of the embedded expression *only contains an uninterrupted string of digits* it is padded on the left with the digit "0" if necessary.

**WIDTH     = len**: If the value of len is less than the minimum required length, it is ignored. This means that the predefined length cannot be reduced, only increased